Spring Boot 3.1 JMS application - 'CodedCharSetId' not setting to 5026 in IBM MQ v9.3 (Linux)
I'm trying to set the 'CodedCharSetId' attribute to 5026 within the MQMD header for messages sent from my Spring Boot 3.1 JMS application to an IBM MQ server (v9.3, Linux).
Here's what I've done:

MessagePostProcessor Implementation: I created a JmsMessagePostProcessor class to modify the message properties before sending. Inside the postProcessMessage method, I'm setting the following properties:


WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_ENCODING to '785' (assuming this represents the desired encoding)
WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_CHARACTER_SET to '5026' (the target character set)


Sending the Message: I'm using the convertAndSend method of org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate to send the message to the MQ server.

The Problem:
I expect the MQMD to show:

Encoding: 785 CodedCharSetId: 5026

However, the actual MQMD shows:

Encoding: 785 CodedCharSetId: 930 (This value seems to be overridden)

What's Odd:
I can successfully set CodedCharSetId to other values like 932, but specifically for 5026, it always gets overridden to 930.
Request for Advice:
Can you suggest any reasons why this might be happening and how I can ensure the CodedCharSetId is set to 5026 in the MQMD?

You must not specify the "desired encoding" or the "target character set", but the encoding and character set which best describe your current message data. I guess you don't need to alter anything for these properties. Conversion would take place when consuming the data.
But if your intention is to actually specify your message data ccsid because your data is currently coded like this, then please note national language ccsid's support depends on the OS. Ccsid 5026 seems to be supported only on z/OS and IBM i (although conversion is available on other platforms). Check whether ccsid 943 or 5050 might be a fit for your data. It is documented here.

That's really helpful! To provide some additional context for your understanding, here's some background on this question.We're currently migrating our MQ servers across three platforms (Z/OS, Windows, and Linux). One of the Z/OS servers will be replaced with a new Linux server. However, the existing Windows and Linux servers won't have any changes to their MQ configurations.Before the migration, messages were sent from the Z/OS server to both the Windows and Linux servers. The MQMD (message descriptor) of these messages has a 'CodedCharSetId' of 5026.

To avoid any disruption on the receiving servers, we want to keep the 'CodedCharSetId' at 5026 in the messages sent from the new Linux server. Otherwise, character encoding mismatches might occur during message reception, leading to garbled characters.

It seems the 'CodedCharSetId' of 5026 is always getting overwritten to 930, likely due to a definition in the ccsid.tbl file.  As a potential solution, could we add another definition for 5026 in the ccsid_part2.tbl file?  Your advice on this approach would be much appreciated.

Sorry, I don't have any experience in updating ccsid_part2.tbl. I don't feel confident to give any advise on that. I understand you want to keep 5026 to keep changes as small as possible, but if this is a good idea really depends on the data which is produced on the new platform (Linux). Is it really the same or may it have platform dependent differences when it produces Kanji/Katakana. In this case I would first check whether either 943 or 5050 is a better fit for your originating data.
